# Trouble Installing mcrypt in PHP

Tags: php, installation, mcrypt

I have uncommented mycrypt in php.ini and restarted Apache, but mycrypt does not enable. I checked using phpinfo(). I have also verified the dll exists in the ext directory.

Any thoughts?

Environment:
Windows Web Server 2008
PHP Version (5.2.5)
Database ( MySQL 5.0.45)
Web Server (Apache 2.0.59)

Answer (score 0):

check comments to [`mcrypt` installation guide](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.installation.php) from php.net:

> Mcrypt.dll should be included in the WINDOWS installer of PHP. Or in
>   the WINDOWS installer of phpmyadmin.
>
> If you wish to install mcrypt on Windows, you should also place
>   libmcrypt.dll in the PATH of your system.

Comment: libmcrypt.dll is in /php and 
mcrypt.dll is in /php/ext